# Want to install rails / nokogiri on Mac OS Majove - but fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Seems to be not the only one with this issue.

I want to install rails 5 on Mac OS Majove. Rails 5 needs nokogiri. But this failes.

I have installed libxml2 with brew:

```
brew install libxml2
```

And installed the xcode Command Line Tools :

```
xcode-select --install
```

Then I try :

```
gem install nokogiri -v '1.10.7' -- --use-system-libraries --with-xml2-include=$(brew --prefix libxml2)/include/libxml2
```

But I get :

```
Building native extensions with: '--use-system-libraries --with-xml2-include=/usr/loca /opt/libxml2/include/libxml2'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/alf/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.7/ext/nokogiri
/Users/alf/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/ruby -I /Users/alf/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0 -r ./siteconf20200206-38583-1bhjmgp.rb extconf.rb --use-system-libraries --with-xml2-include\=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include/libxml2
checking if the C compiler accepts  -I /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/libxml2... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
checking for xmlParseDoc() in libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc() in libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for exsltFuncRegister() in libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for xmlHasFeature()... yes
checking for xmlFirstElementChild()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlSchemaSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlSchemaSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/alf/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.7/ext/nokogiri
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/alf/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.7/ext/nokogiri
make "DESTDIR="

make failed, uncaught signal 9

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/alf/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/alf/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.5.0/nokogiri-1.10.7/gem_make.out
```

The
`/Users/alf/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.5.0/nokogiri-1.10.7/gem_make.out` is not very helping because it contains the same content I already see on the console.

Comment: I'm not sure what this could be... Signal 9 is SIGKILL; possibly your machine is out of memory??! What happens if you `cd /Users/alf/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.7/ext/nokogiri`, then run `make -d` (debug mode)?

Comment: Maybe you could use rails inside a docker container?